# Ubuntu server: ssh login is very slow

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-11.10

I have a server hooked directly up to the internet, no router. But when I go to login to ssh it is VERY slow. It is not the connection as you can see here by the response time on this ping:
[image: ping operation average ms=3.769]

What settings do I need to tweek in order to speed up the login process.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the server can resolve the address you're SSHing from to a hostname. That or disable the `UseDNS` option in the sshd configuration. But preferably the first.

Comment: I couldn't find the `UseDNS` option in the config files, so how do I setup my network to be able to be resolved to a hostname.

Comment: @sightofnick: that's more a job for your ISP. regarding slow-ssh: http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.3

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, make sure the line that begins with `host:` reads:

```
host: files dns
```

Apparently Ubuntu somethimes have problems with avahi-daemon and `mdns4_minimal` / `mdns4`.

I had problems with slow ssh connections when my `nsswitch.conf` read:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

I didn't try only removing the NOTFOUND clause. Perhaps that would have helped too.